# Where do we configure "minimum approval status" for a Web 8.5 solution using Topology Manager?

Tags: publishing, workflow, web8.5, topology-manager

I want to prevent unapproved items publishing to Live.

In Tridion 2013 we configure the Publication Target "minimum approval status".

We have a new Web 8.5 solution using Topology Manager so we do not have Publication Management in the GUI.

Where do we configure "minimum approval status" for a Web 8.5 solution using Topology Manager?

docs.sdl site only details the old way with publication targets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Topology Manager based publishing, the Minimal Approval Status is defined on a Target Type (which is part of a Business Process Type).

Comment: Thanks, Rick .

docs.sdl.com just needs an update to mention the new location when using Topology Manager configured solution.